# Tkinter looped key binding not working

Tags: python, for-loop, binding, tkinter

I made a working piece of code, intended to support key-controlled movement of an object on canvas:

```
self.can = tk.Canvas(master, width=100, height=100)
self.can.grid()

self.can.bind('<Right>', lambda event: self.move(0))
self.can.bind('<Down>', lambda event: self.move(90))
self.can.bind('<Left>', lambda event: self.move(180))
self.can.bind('<Up>', lambda event: self.move(270))

self.can.focus_set()

def move(self, dir):
    if dir == 0:
        print 'right'
    elif dir == 90:
        print 'down'
    elif dir == 180:
        print 'left'
    elif dir == 270:
        print 'up'
```

I don't have an object yet, so I just test the key binding. That's fine. But then I tried to optimize stuff and put these bindings in a loop

```
x = 0
for i in ['<Right>', '<Down>', '<Left>', '<Up>']:
    self.can.bind(i, lambda event: self.move(x))
    x += 90
```

... it stopped working. No errors, but no binding either. Maybe it's all about the `event` argument of `.bind()` function - I thought it's a common `string`, but found no evidence of this or the opposite in the web. How do I keep things nice and short, if I'm quite sure the amount of visually similar bindings will keep on growing and I don't want any copy-paste in my code?

upd: found out that binding shouldn't be looked upon as a functional part of code and thus requires no aesthetic shortening. But I'm still curious why didn't that work and what the `event` argument consists of.

Comment: Why put them in a loop? The result is less clear, prone to common mistakes (such as the one you are experiencing), and uses the same number of lines of code. You gain nothing by doing this in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is because for all bindings, x will be equal to 360. Lambda will fetch current x value when they are executed. When it happens x = 360.

This quick fix, should fix the problem:

```
self.can.bind(i, lambda event, xx=x: self.move(xx))
```

Comment: Thank you, that might work for me. But Bryan's right, shortening this really isn't that necessary.